# disableSelection on everything except input[type=text]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to use jQuery's "disableSelection()" function because I have a lot of drag and drop on the pages but I do not want to disable selection on input boxes, just everything else.

I have tried

```
$('body').disableSelection(); $('input').enableSelection();

$('body').not('input').disableSelection();
```

still DISABLES EVERYTHING ON THE PAGE. Thank you.

Comment: What does "still no luck" mean?

Comment: it means, I tried what I said I tried and had no luck.

Comment: @Tim looking and no luck  is not question buddy . Tell what happend what error you got what is not working

Comment: I know what the term means in general; I don't know what it means in this particular case. You need to be specific about how those code snippets didn't work. What results do you get? Does it disable selection on everything? On nothing?

Comment: it's not a big deal, you just needed to ask and not be cryptic about your question either...

Comment: I was faced with a similar problem, but the accepted solution didn't work for me - I was still able to select elements that are ancestors of an input element.  I implemented an alternate solution described in the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11331561/13087

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With

```
$('body').not('input').disableSelection();
```

You disable selection on every instance of `body` that is not an `input`. Since body is not an input this will just disable selection on body.

Try this:

```
$('body *').not(':has(input)').not('input').disableSelection();
```

However, like other people pointed out it's probably pretty useless disabling selection on things that aren't draggable in the first place. So maybe you should replace `body` with `.drag` or however you can select all the objects that are draggable (keeping the rest of the function the same).

Comment: Thanks Kokos, this makes complete sense but still didn't work. Should I loop through each element on the page and check for an input then disable whatever isn't an input?

Comment: That's actually what that code does, it looks for every element within body that is not an input and disables it. What exactly 'didn't work'?

Comment: everything is still disabled, including the input boxes

Comment: Hm, that makes sense now that I think about it. It will still disable the selection on the parent. See my updated code.

Comment: You rock! Thanks Kokos! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so `disableSelection` will work for input textboxes. It's useful for making text elements, or elements that contain text, not text-selectable. For example, if you have a draggable element, you may not want text selection to occur when the user goes to drag the element.

Comment: With that in sight, it would make sense to `disableSelection` only on draggable elements, probably in the method that initiate these elements.