# disableSelection on everything but input[type=text]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a requirement to disable selection on a web page for everything except input[type=text] elements.

[This accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7109491/13087) to a similar question almost does the trick, but it doesn't disable selection for containers that contain input[type=text] elements.  Therefore the user can still select by starting a drag operation from within one of these containers.

Is this even possible, i.e. is it possible to disable selection for a container element, while enabling it for child elements (specifically, child input=text elements).

> @Pointy, "Why not just take out that first .not() call?"

Taking out the first `.not` call, will give:

```
$('body').not('input').disableSelection();
```

which, as pointed out in the linked question, will still disable everything on the page, including the input[type=text] elements.

> @David Thomas, "Do you have a live demo ..."

I don't have a live demo, but it's fairly trivial.  For example, a div with a bit of padding that contains an input[type=text] element.  The result is:

- With `$('body').not('input').disableSelection();` selectiopn is disabled for all the page, including the input elements.
- With `$('body *').not(':has(input)').not('input').disableSelection();` selection is disabled for all elements that don't contain an input element.  But it is possible to select the whole page by starting a drag operation from within a container that contains an input element.

Comment: Why not just take out that first `.not()` call?

Comment: And what have you got so far, what's your ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML? Do you have a live demo we can see working, or failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution that appears to do what I want, and would be interested in comments / improvements from jquery / javascript experts.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").disableSelection();

    $("body").delegate('input[type=text],textarea', "focus", function () {
        $("body").enableSelection();
    });

    $("body").delegate("input[type=text],textarea", "blur", function () {
        $("body").disableSelection();
    });
});
```

When a textbox (input[type=text] or textarea) has the focus, then dragging with the mouse only selects text within the textbox.  Therefore it's "safe" to enable selection for the whole page while a textbox has focus (between focus and blur events).

There is a noticeable delay when tabbing between textboxes on IE8/9.  It's not noticeable on Google Chrome, which I understand has a faster javascript engine.  So I can live with the performance hit, especially since IE10 is going to have a faster javascript engine.

**UPDATE**

When using ASP.NET `UpdatePanel`, this needs to be modified to disable selection after each partial postback:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
    $("body").disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, cinch up your suspenders and get ready for a **really dirty hack**.

### Disclaimer:

I don't think this is a good way to do things. I simply wanted to tackle the challenge of getting the OP's desired functionality. If someone else can get this to work in a cleaner way, please post it.

---

After playing around with the `disableSelection()` function, it seemed that if a parent element had been disabled, all of its children would be unselectable as well (*please correct me if I'm wrong*). So, I decided that if you wanted *everything* to be unselectable except small parts, you could put all of your markup in one unselectable `<div>` and use absolute positioning to place selectable clones of your `<input>` tags (or any tag, really) on top of the unselectable ones. These clones would reside in a second `<div>` that was not disabled.

Here's an example of this idea: http://jsfiddle.net/pnCxE/2/.

#### Drawbacks:

- Styling becomes a big headache. Any element that relies on a parent's style (i.e., position, size, colors, etc.) cannot be cloned since the clones reside in a separate place.
- Forms become much harder to manage since (again) the clone isn't in the same place as the cloned element.
- You have to deal with naming collisions since the clone will have the same ID as the cloned element. (It's doable; I just didn't want to code it since it would probably need specific attention by anyone that uses this idea)

So, while you *can* work around the selectable limitations, you might be better off just accepting the container selection. I would think long and hard before putting this code into a production environment.

Comment: +1 for the creative solution.  However, apart from the drawbacks you mention, it doesn't quite achieve what I want as is - it is possible to select "unselectable" text by starting a drag operation from within a selectable area (e.g. below the button, or from within the selectable 'p' element).

Comment: @Joe - Starting the drag from below the button is only possible because it is jsFiddle; if you inspect the HTML, everything below the button is outside the `<body>` tag. If you use this code on a normal HTML page that doesn't use an `<iframe>` that type of selection wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Joe - Updated to only allow textboxes to be cloned. This prevents selection spilling out onto you unselectable regions.

Comment: thanks again for your help, but I've found an alternative that seems better to me.  See my own answer.  What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, although it is same with what you're already using:

```
$('* :not(input)').disableSelection();
```

I don't get though why do you have to use entire `body` element and not narrow it down to text nodes (p, h[..], ul, ol etc.)

And I agree with @David Thomas - it would be easier to see a test page you're working on.